# Implementing custom scrollable arc (circullar) viewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, android-custom-view, viewgroup

I have been working with Android for about 4 months. I need some guidance on how to implement something like this:

[image]

In that picture I've used three of the custom viewGroups (calling it ArcScrollView) stacked on top of on another which is what I am trying to achieve.

The questions that I have are:

1. Do I need to extend ViewGroup, frameLayout or what?
2. How can I make it scrollable?

I took a look at LinearLayout source code and it was extending frameLayout but again LinearLayout is not scrollable and need to be hosted by a scrollView.

I need to have complete control over scrolling because these arcScrollView are rectangles and I need onTouchIntercept of the viewGroup to return false (not consuming) at certain positions.

3. Is scrolling actually just changing the starting position of the first child view and putting them after one another or something magical that Android does?
4. I think I need to override the onDraw method also for drawing the partial circle. Does that effect anything that I need to worry about?
5. Should I override the ScrollView and LinearLayout instead? because I think there is a lot that have been implemented in them.

Comment: What you could do is use the ReyclerView's LayoutManager Api, and create a new LayoutManager with orientation ARC, then other people also could use your code directly

Comment: @Bhargav ohh, i hadn't thought of a custom LayoutManager.. haven't work with it but i will read up on it. If i manage to get to work i surly will share the code. Thanks for the suggestion